# Cartopy: Albers Equal Area projection not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, cartopy, pyproj

I am trying to plot a topographic raster in Cartopy. I have downloaded some sample GeoTIFF data from this database: https://zenodo.org/record/3940482. I then import the data and metadata using the Python GDAL library:

```
from osgeo import gdal                                                          

data_object = gdal.Open(path_geotiff)                                       
data_array = data_object.ReadAsArray()                                      
data_transform = data_object.GetGeoTransform()                                                                       
proj_wkt = data_object.GetProjection()
```

I need to get the projection as a Cartopy object, which I achieve using the PyProj library for an intermediate step:

```
from pyproj.crs import CRS                          
proj_crs = CRS.from_wkt(proj_wkt) 

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
proj_cartopy = ccrs.Projection(proj_crs)
```

This seems to work, and indicates that the projection is one of those supported by Cartopy, Albers Equal Area:

```
>>> print(proj_cartopy)
PROJCRS["Albers",BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",DATUM["North American Datum 1983",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4269]],CONVERSION["unnamed",METHOD["Albers Equal Area",ID["EPSG",9822]],PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8821]],PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-106,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8822]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8824]],PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8826]],PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8827]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

I then try to create a GeoAxes object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
subplot_kw = dict(projection = proj_cartopy)                                
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw = subplot_kw)
```

However, I receive a NotImplemented error:

```
File "/Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/envs/carto/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1598, in _boundary path, = cpatch.geos_to_path(self.projection.boundary)
File "/Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/envs/carto/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 679, in boundary
raise NotImplementedError
```

Please help me to understand this error (I know I could manually enter the projection, for example using the EPSG code, but I prefer to keep my current automatic method if possible).

Comment: `This seems to work, and indicates that the projection is  ...`  No, it could be just some descriptions or something that are not ready for use as CRS/projection, and may cause the errors you experienced. Try `help(ccrs.Projection)` to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is something that is not fully supported yet.

- https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/813
- https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/153
- https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/923